# Converting date written in arabic numbers to english then converting the time from 12h to 24h

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, data-analysis

I have a date column that has an arabic date and time format, also it's a 12h system, and the date doesn’t always have 2 digits if the month is separate for example it shows a single 9 nor 09

the date looks like this:
 ٢٥‏/٩‏/٢٠١٩ ١٠:٠٧ ص

When I convert the column to a list it looks like this:
'٢٥\u200f/٩\u200f/٢٠١٩ ١٠:٠٧ ص'

This is a photo of the date column:

[image]

CSV file for the date column:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BMsuzrb5CLGVEPTxxULfOKOLzKb_7Uwi/view?usp=sharing

I want it to be in English datetime format and in 24h system, if possible.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32859847/python-date-conversion-how-to-convert-arabic-date-string-into-date-or-datetime) can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `unicode` lib:

```
from unidecode import unidecode
from datetime import datetime

result = datetime.strptime(unidecode('٦‏/١١‏/٢٠١٨ ٨:١٢ م').replace('S', 'A').replace('m', 'P') + 'M', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p')
```

Output:

```
2018-11-06 20:12:00
```

Comment: S means AM, and M means PM, is there a way to convert your output to 24h system?

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: ٦‏/١١‏/٢٠١٨ ٨:١٢ م this is 8:12 PM the output is 8:12 not correct, and sorry the M in the previous comment is actually small m not M

Comment: S means AM, and m means PM

Comment: So what is the full expected result for `٢٥‏/٩‏/٢٠١٩ ١٠:٠٧ ص`?

Comment: the case you mentioned is an AM case, the output is perfect, but when there is a PM case "m" it doesn’t add 12 h it just remove the letter m,  PM case '٦‏/١١‏/٢٠١٨ ٨:١٢ م'

Comment: Try my updated answer

Comment: from unidecode import unidecode
from datetime import datetime

result = datetime.strptime(unidecode('٦‏/١١‏/٢٠١٨ ٨:١٢ م').replace('S', 'A').replace('m', 'P') + 'M', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %p')

Comment: the above comment output should be '2018-11-06 20:12:00'

Comment: Try again my updated answer

Comment: i know you get that a lot but you’re simply an absolute legend, thank you very much, last thing, what is the best way to apply it to this column df.date ?

Comment: This is unrelated topic. Please post another question.

Comment: will do know, thank you :)